# Adding a variable to end of a mysql query in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

Im trying to add a variable to the end of a sql query in the following way:

```
<sql:query var="result" sql="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customer_number = <% $x %> />
```

but its not inputing the variable into the sql query.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `x` is the variable set somewhere in request/session/applicationcontext/pagecontext the following will work

```
<sql:query var="result" sql="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customer_number = $x />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the very first example in this link

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html

I think you have gotten the syntax wrong. It goes like

```
<c:set var="bid" value="${param.Add}"/>
<sql:query var="books" >
  select * from PUBLIC.books where id = ?
  <sql:param value="${bid}" />
</sql:query>
```